# Prepared Statement in Android - syntax error (code 1)

Tags: android, sql

I'm getting a SQLite syntax exception that I can't seem to figure out:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "index": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO messageAttachments(typeId,index,attachmentId,messageId) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

This exception is thrown in the code below:

```
MessageAttachment attachment = message.attachments.get(i);
        ContentValues messageAttachmentValues = new ContentValues();
messageAttachmentValues.put(MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS_ATTACHMENT_ID, attachment.getId());
messageAttachmentValues.put(MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS_MESSAGE_ID, message.id);
messageAttachmentValues.put(MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS_INDEX, i);

switch (attachment.getAttachmentType()) {
    case text:
        messageAttachmentValues.put(MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS_TYPE_ID, MESSAGE_ATTACHMENT_TYPES_TEXT_ID);
        break;
    case image:
        messageAttachmentValues.put(MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS_TYPE_ID, MESSAGE_ATTACHMENT_TYPES_IMAGE_ID);
        break;
    case voice:
        messageAttachmentValues.put(MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS_TYPE_ID, MESSAGE_ATTACHMENT_TYPES_VOICE_ID);
        break;
}

boolean attachmentSuccess = db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS, null, messageAttachmentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE) != -1;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: index is a keyword. Use some other identifier

Comment: `index` is a reserved word - you need to escape it: `...INTO messageAttachments(typeId,[index],attachmentId...`

Comment: index is reserved keyword in sqlite. Try to use different column name.

Comment: Thanks for the help!